# Can't Launch Software Updater From Toolbar

Tags: update-manager

I was able to do it last week but, now, the Software Updater does not respond to clicks.  Everything else in the toolbar does.  The icon is green which indicates that there are updates available.  I can run `sudo update-manager` from the command-line and it launches.

How can I get the icon to work?  I am running Unity on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS inside a VM.

**EDIT 1**

I've noticed when I hit `Alt-Tab` it shows the Software Updater.  It won't bring up the window when I switch to it and it is nowhere to be found on any of my desktops. I can also see `update-manager` in the process table:

```
$ ps -ef | grep update-manager
stephen   5565  1907  0 07:40 ?        00:00:04 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager --no-update --no-focus-on-map
stephen   5691  5621  0 08:04 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto update-manager
```

It seems like the update-manager is starting automatically somehow but not displaying.  I can kill it from the command-line and click on the icon to launch it but it seems that it automatically gets into a bad state somehow.

Comment: needs restart..

Comment: @KasiyA, The whole VM needs a restart?

Comment: This is actually a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1003950 if you scroll down to the last comment #53 someone has posted a workaround for 14.04 (I haven't tried it, so not sure if it works). would help if you mark the bug as affecting you.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisCarter, I actually reported it as a bug earlier today.  I've now made my report a duplicate of 1003950 and said it affects me.  I'll try the workaround the next time it happens.

Comment: @ChrisCarter, running `wmctrl -R 'Software Updater'`, as described in https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1003950/comments/53, causes the window to reappear.